# Angular Validation not working for pattern attribute

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to test validation on this control but when I take the digits down to `9` and back to `10` the validation is still `invalid`.

```
<input type="tel" #phone="ngModel" required pattern="^\d{10}$" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="phone.invalid && phone.touched" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="userModel.phone">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use pattern attribute like this ::

```
<input [name]="fullName" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" ngModel>
```

More information about pattern validator ::

https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator

https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example